# Cloud Firestore trigger for Cloud Function to invoke Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to run some code that is packaged as a java jar in response to a change in Google firestore entity. 
I want an event-based trigger to invoke this jar. Basically, any change(create/delete/update) to the firestore entity I have to propagate to an external system. 
My requirements are:

1. Invoke external service in response to onWrite triggers on a Google Firestore table
2. Ordering is important for my use case but I do not expect changes to the datastore entity to happen at sub-second intervals, it will more likely be few minutes apart
3. I want to prefer serverless/managed service option over running my own VM / containers for example.

The design option I am considering are:

1. Use Cloud Function to pick up changes and invoke a cloud composer workflow to run my code
   onWriteTrigger -> Cloud Function -> Cloud Composer workflow
2. Use Cloud Function to pick up the changes and send this to a PubSub topic and then invoke the composer workflow. 
   onWriteTrigger -> Cloud Function -> PubSub topic -> Cloud Composer workflow
3. Run my code within Cloud Function. If my code takes 10 to 15 minutes to run, is this a suitable option for me?

One thing I am concerned about is the trigger from Firestore is beta. Is it likely that Google decide to change something and my code stops working. Can I safely use this feature in production.

I would like some inputs please on the best way forward from these options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can add trigger function with firestore. Firestore is used by quite a few companies. So I think it's safe to use in production.

You can use the following cloud function:

```
export const incomingPatientNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('collectionName/{documentId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const date = snapshot.data();

    // Here you can send a post request to invoke your composer workflow.
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which of the my 3 design options would you say I should go for.

Comment: I like the first one.